# PDO fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) вопрос

Tags: php, pdo

Вопрос: **Как через `foreach()` сделать вывод `FETCH_OBJ`?**

Нужно вывести все строки из базы, вот что я делаю

```
$opt = array("PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE             => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION",
              "PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ");
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lala", 'root', '', $opt);

$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `users`";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);    
$stmt->execute();


foreach($stmt as $user){
    echo $user[0];
}
```

Все в порядке, выводит все результаты, НО дело в том, что 
`$stmt->execute()` - возвращает мне массив **ассоциатавниый и индексированый вместе**

> `Array ( [id] => 18 [0] => 18 [login] => admin [1] => admin [pswd] => 55d34e03cca66 [2] => 55d34e03cca66 [email] => fsdfsd@mail.ru [3] => fsdfsd@mail.ru [forget] => 12345 [4] => 12345 )`

А если  пытаюсь добавить в `$opt - FETCH_OBJ` , или напрямую подставить

```
$res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Мне выдает в ответ 1 строчку ответа, вне массива. 
Если так делаю

```
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
    echo $result->id;
}
```

так все прекрасно работает.

Comment: Ну так и делайте тем способом, который "прекрасно работает".

Comment: @user190134, cмотрите примеры правильного использования функций http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тьфу! :)))
Залез в исходники, раскопал реализацию итератора, убедился что там используется режим по умолчанию, написал тест, долго чесал репу, пока наконец не дошло: в **кавычках** в РНР пишутся только **строки**. Это надо очень крепко запомнить. Ни переменные, ни константы, ни синтаксис добавления элементов в массив в кавычках писать нельзя!

```
$opt = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
             PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

В остальном делаешь всё правильно, так держать.

Comment: И правда, протупил , забыл что константы указываются..)